# How can I make change for existing date value in SQL Server into new value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know how can I make change for existing date value in SQL Server into new value?

Example:

```
Declare @StartDate DATETIME; SET @StartDate = '2010-07-07 00:00:00'
```

Which I hope to declare another variable @DATETIME2 DATETIME based on @StartDate value changed into '2010-07-07 08:00:00' instead of default manually hard code it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [DateAdd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function:

```
DECLARE @DateTime2 DateTime; Set @DateTime2 = DATEADD(hh, 8, @StartDate)
```